# Comparing the color of two cells and deleting the rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to highlight cells in two of the columns in my sheet cells that contain the same string in red and after that delete all the rows the contain the rows that have the two red cells.

This is what I came up so far. The first stage works but then I tried to compare the color of two cell and it didn't work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim WhatFor As String

WhatFor = InputBox("Enter your search word to highlight", "Search Criteria")
If WhatFor = Empty Then Exit Sub

Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=WhatFor, _
  TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub


Sub Macro2()

Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range

cell = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range

i = 1

Do While Cells("A, i").Value <> ""

    If cell("A, i").Interior And cell("F, i").Interior = 13551615 Then:      
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

[image: example of my sheet]

Comment: it makes absolutely no sense to color the cells? just delete the rows

Comment: You are probably right but comparing two parts of strings is to complicated for me. The values are not **"Equal"** in reality but most of the time "similar".

Comment: Are you saying delete rows were a stated string is found more than once, in different cells, within the same row, and where that string is a match ignoring case? They exist as separate strings, not a substring within a longer string? Is the string to be the only item within the cell?

Comment: that tells me that you do not colour the cells with your code.  ... so how are the cells getting coloured then?

Comment: @jsotola The `Macro1` code is setting conditional formatting for cells that **contain** the desired string - i.e. a `Like "*" & WhatFor & "*"`.

Comment: In case I would like to delete the row without coloring the cells - how would the basic code should be? I need to compare the cells like in "search" not like "equal". Comparing only part of the string in each cell.

Thank :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Error in your Code is in the condition of your IF statement:

```
  If (Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = 13551615) And (Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = 13551615) Then
```

should be:

```
If (cell("A, i").Interior = 13551615) And (cell("F, i").Interior = 13551615) Then:
```

Unfortunately, Conditional formatting does not affect the .InteriorColor. It does change the color of the cell, but we cannot check it this way.

Checking the actual displayed color is currently not possible.

It is possible to build a function which emulates the condition in all conditional formats of the cell, but that function will have to be updated whenever Microsoft adds another type of condition for conditional formats. A very good example of how it could be done can be found: [here](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)?p=1168&viewfull=1#post1168): (Please note that this function returns the colorindez rather than the color)

---

Another logical problem is in way you delete the rows:

```
'This method does not check each row!
i = 1
Do While Cells(i, "A").Value <> ""
    If '<your condition>
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Let's suppose that `i = 5`, and you want to delete that line.
The original row 5 is deleted, row 6 becomes row 5, row 7 becomes row 6, etc.

Then i becomes 6, and you check that row (which originally was row 7 ...)

That way, the original row 6 is never checked ...

In cases like this, it is generally best to start at the last row, and work upwards. Or you can use the `.rows` property and a `FOR EACH` construction:

```
Dim row As Range

For Each row In [A1].CurrentRegion.Rows
  If Intersect(row, [B:B]).Value Like "*" & WhatFor  & "*" Then
    row.Delete
  End If
Next row
```

(This version checks only 1 column, using column B as an example)

---

However, the Answer to your problem is what jsotola said:
" it makes absolutely no sense to color the cells? just delete the rows" – *jsotola 17 mins ago*

---

In case I would like to delete the row without coloring the cells - how would the basic code should be? I need to compare the cells like in "search" not like "equal". Comparing only part of the string in each cell.

Thank :-)     - *yaeer, 1 minute ago*

Comment: There are other problems in the OP's code - the use of `"A, i"` is just one of them.  (It's just the one that is replicated in your answer so needs to be fixed for your answer to be part of the solution.)  Another problem I noticed was `Dim cell As Range` `cell = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range`.  That's when I gave up looking.

Comment: You are probably right but comparing two parts of strings is to complicated for me. The values are not "Equal" in reality but most of the time "similar". – yaeer 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: Also the code in the answer is still a single-line `If` (due to the `:` on the end) and will cause a "End If without block If" syntax error.  So I suggest you fix that up in the answer too.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, I see.  Trying to figure out how to correct this part of the code in a way that actually helps yaeer ...

Comment: FWIW, I'm not even sure whether a conditional format actually updates the cell's `.Interior.Color` property anyway.  I don't do that sort of thing very often (if ever) so would need to test that it is actually a valid thing to test.

Comment: the conditional formatting works - it's based on a recorded macro. I just added the input box. This is the way I tried to create and easy way to search and compare between the cells.

Comment: @YowE3K Apparently it doesn't afect the `.Interior.Color` - I'll have another look at this ...

Comment: first I use macro 1 then macro 2

Comment: In case I would like to delete the row without coloring the cells - how would the basic code should be? I need to compare the cells like in "search" not like "equal". Comparing only part of the string in each cell. Thank :-) –